Evaluation of Definite Integrals
I am currently evaluating the following Fourier integral:
$$ G(k, \omega) = \frac{\alpha}{ \omega - Y_1} \\
\int_{-∞}^{∞} \frac{1}{(2\pi)}G(k,\omega) e^{i\omega t} dw$$
Using the residue theorem, as described in Chapter 7 of Mathematical Methods for Physicists by George B. Arfken, I computed the integral for different values of tt. My results are:
for t > 0  the result is :
$$ -i e^{-iY_1 t} $$
and for t < 0 the result is :
$$ i e^{-iY_1 t}$$
However, when I computed the same integral using Mathematica, I obtained the following result:
$$\sqrt{2\pi}  Y_1 \delta(t) + i \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}  sign(t) $$
There seems to be a discrepancy between my solution and Mathematica's output, particularly with the presence of the Dirac delta function and the sign function.
Could someone clarify whether my solution using the residue theorem is correct, or if there is an underlying reason for the differences in the results from Mathematica? What might account for the appearance of the delta function and the sign function in Mathematica's solution?

You should make clear; is $Y_1\in\mathbb R$? Is $\alpha\in\mathbb R$? How can $\alpha$ not appear in the final solution?

I see $\omega$ and $w$ in the same formula.  I assume they are actually supposed to be the same.

Usually the energy has a small (or finite) imaginary part ($Y_1=E_0 \pm i\eta$), which forces closing the integration contour in one half plane (upper or lower), and the integral gives finite or zero value, depending on whether the pole lies within or outsize the contour. I think Fetter&Walecka and other "pedestrian level" books cover it... while something like AGD calls it "standard analytical continuation techniques".
For example ($\eta>0$, sometimes $\pm \eta$ is written as $+0^{\pm}$):
$$
I(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{i\omega t}}{\omega -\omega_0+i\eta}d\omega
$$
First we can shift the integration contour, by making a change of variable $\Omega = \omega + i\eta$:
$$
I(t)=
\int_{-\infty-i\eta}^{+\infty-i\eta}\frac{e^{i\omega t-\eta t}}{\omega -\omega_0}d\omega=
\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}
\int_{-R-i\eta}^{+R-i\eta}\frac{e^{i\omega t-\eta t}}{\omega -\omega_0}d\omega
$$
we now close the contour by an arc of radius $R$: if $t>0$ we close it in the upper half plane, where the imaginary part of $\omega$ would be positive, so that $e^{i\omega t}\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow +\infty$, and the arc contribution vanishes. The pole at $\omega=\omega_0$ is then within the integration contour and the answer is
$$
I(t)=2\pi i e^{i\omega_0 t}
$$
If $t < 0$, we close the contour in the lower half plane, so that the pole finds itself outside the integrationn contour, and the answer is zero. Thus
$$
I(t)=2\pi i e^{i\omega_0 t}\theta(t)=2\pi i e^{i\omega_0 t}\begin{cases}1, \text{ if } t > 0,\\
0, \text{ if } t < 0\end{cases}
$$

(image source)
Caution I might have made a mistake somewhere, as I did the calculation on the fly. So the answer may be completely opposite (or correct for a different sign in the complex exponent.)

you have changed variable and introduced a new var Omega and why you didn't use that ?
